# how to apply group_by-like method on columns of a data set that has a dataframe as result without for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, vectorization

## Context and preperations

I have difficulty with explaining what the question is, but I'll try my best. The data we have is as follows, a questionaire with a handful of questions on the Likert-scale (1-7):

```
set.seed(1234)
results <- data.frame(
  user = paste0("V", 1:10),
  measurement = "0m",
  q1 = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q2 = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q3 = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q4 = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q5 = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q6 = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

So this is the zeroth measurement, each row indicates an individual answering questions 1 through 6.

```
> as_tibble(results) %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  user  measurement    q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6
  <chr> <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 V1    0m              4     2     6     2     1     1
2 V2    0m              2     7     4     5     3     6
3 V3    0m              6     6     4     2     6     3
4 V4    0m              5     2     5     6     4     6
5 V5    0m              4     6     4     7     2     1
6 V6    0m              7     7     3     3     3     5
```

Now we classify a score <6 as "bad" and otherwise good. Let's prepare the data:

```
  classifications <- dplyr::mutate(
    results,
    across(
      where(is.numeric),
      ~case_when(
        .x < 6 ~ "bad",
        TRUE ~ "good"
      )
    )
  )
  data <- left_join(
    results,
    classifications,
    by = c("user", "measurement"),
    suffix = c("_score", "_class")
  )
```

```
> as_tibble(data) %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 × 14
  user  measurement q1_score q2_score q3_score q4_score q5_score q6_score q1_class q2_class q3_class q4_class q5_class q6_class
  <chr> <chr>          <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 V1    0m                 4        2        6        2        1        1 bad      bad      good     bad      bad      bad     
2 V2    0m                 2        7        4        5        3        6 bad      good     bad      bad      bad      good    
3 V3    0m                 6        6        4        2        6        3 good     good     bad      bad      good     bad     
4 V4    0m                 5        2        5        6        4        6 bad      bad      bad      good     bad      good    
5 V5    0m                 4        6        4        7        2        1 bad      good     bad      good     bad      bad     
6 V6    0m                 7        7        3        3        3        5 good     good     bad      bad      bad      bad
```

## The question

I want to analyse people that score bad and good on a specific question, say `q2`: how did a "good" person score on average on all other questions, and how did a "bad" person score on average on all other questions? Like so:

```
> group_by(data, measurement, q2_class) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean))
# A tibble: 2 × 8
# Groups:   measurement [1]
  measurement q2_class q1_score q2_score q3_score q4_score q5_score q6_score
  <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 0m          bad          4.67     2.67     6        4        3.33     2.67
2 0m          good         4.29     6.29     4.43     4.43     4.14     2.71
```

However, I want to do this for **all questions now** and have it as output in one table. I have a solution with a couple of for-loops, but I'm looking into a vectorized option. The problem is that each output is a table, so by defining the `group_by(...) %>% summarise()` in a function and calling `across()` will result in a dataframe where all cells are a dataframe. I also saw something coming past using `nest()`, but I'm not familiar with that.

Since this is something that will be done with quite a large data set (100k users asked roughly 70 questions) I'm hoping I can find a nice optimised method. The question also becomes: is it going to be worth it with such a data set, because all these preparations will take some time, so maybe the for loop by looping over all questions will be just as "efficient". Please let me know if extra info needs to be added.

As example, I've saved the result above in `tmp` and created it like so:

```
> rbindlist(list("q1" = tmp, "q2" = tmp), idcol = "question") %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  question measurement class    q1_score q2_score q3_score q4_score q5_score q6_score
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 q1       0m          bad          4.67     2.67     6        4        3.33     2.67
2 q1       0m          good         4.29     6.29     4.43     4.43     4.14     2.71
3 q2       0m          bad          4.67     2.67     6        4        3.33     2.67
4 q2       0m          good         4.29     6.29     4.43     4.43     4.14     2.71
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

# column names starting with "q"
qs = names(results)[grepl("^q",names(results))]

# loop over each of these columns, and bind rows together
bind_rows(lapply(qs,\(q) {
  results %>%
    group_by(class=get(q)<6, measurement) %>%
    summarize(across(all_of(qs), mean),.groups="drop") %>% 
    mutate(question=q, class=if_else(class,"bad","good"))
}))
```

Alternatively, this approach using `data.table` will be much faster, especially on your larger dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(results)

qs = names(results)[grepl("^q",names(results))]

rbindlist(
  lapply(qs, \(q) copy(results)[, `:=`(question=q, class=fifelse(get(q)<6, "bad","good"))])
)[,lapply(.SD, mean), .(question, class, measurement), .SDcols=qs]
```

You might be able to speed this up even a little bit more by melting and joining:

```
melt(
  results, id=c("user", "measurement"),variable.name = "question", value.name = "class"
)[results, on=.(user, measurement)][, lapply(.SD, mean), .(measurement,question, class<6), .SDcols=qs]
```

Output (similiar/same under all three options):

```
# A tibble: 12 × 9
   class measurement    q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6 question
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
 1 good  0m           6.33  6.33  4.67  2.67  5.33  3.33 q1      
 2 bad   0m           3.57  4.71  5     5     3.29  2.43 q1      
 3 good  0m           4.29  6.29  4.43  4.43  4.14  2.71 q2      
 4 bad   0m           4.67  2.67  6     4     3.33  2.67 q2      
 5 good  0m           5     4     6.67  3     4.33  1.33 q3      
 6 bad   0m           4.14  5.71  4.14  4.86  3.71  3.29 q3      
 7 good  0m           4.33  4.67  4.67  6.67  4     2.67 q4      
 8 bad   0m           4.43  5.43  5     3.29  3.86  2.71 q4      
 9 good  0m           5.33  6     5.33  4     6.33  2    q5      
10 bad   0m           4     4.86  4.71  4.43  2.86  3    q5      
11 good  0m           3.5   4.5   4.5   5.5   3.5   6    q6      
12 bad   0m           4.62  5.38  5     4     4     1.88 q6
```

Comment: `lapply()` is basically a for loop right?

Comment: similar yes, see `?lapply`

Comment: All right. So do you also know of a vectorized solution? Basically I'm trying to dodge for loops here.

Comment: as long as you use the data.table approach, I'm not sure I see an efficiency problem here.